# "python setup.py install" Error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: but the file is clearly where it should be

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, pip

Im trying to install the plotly package without using pip and I get the following error message when I run the command "python setup.py install":

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dist\plotly-2.0.15\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    exec (open('plotly/version.py').read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plotly/version.py'
```

Even though the file plotly/version.py is clearly on the folder when I check with the Explorer. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you launched `setup.py` from another directory (higher in hierarchy), probably something like that : `C:\Temp> python dist\plotly-2.0.15\setup.py install`

But, the setup.py assumes that you are executed from the directory where is located `setup.py` (the `exec(open("plotly/version.py"))` will work from where you have launched the script, not from where it is.

So, change your directory to `dist\plotly-2.0.15` before launching setup.py, and it will work :)

Comment: This is the first thing I tried but for some reason the pyhton command is not recognized when I run it from the folder where setup.py is located. I get the following error:

The command "python" is either misspelled or
could not be found.

I come from Mac and this is an error I have never encountered before!

Comment: then, correct your path (python.exe should be in the PATH variable). (type `set` in a cmd to see the PATH variable).